# Called stop() outside of a test context

Tags: javascript, qunit

I created new qunit

```
 QUnit.module("Integration");

 QUnit.moduleStart(withPromise(function(details){
                   ....some logic with promise in q
})
QUnit.moduleDone(withPromise(function(details){
    ....some logic
    }));

  QUnit.test("1. Push  (new file)", function() {

         ..some logic
  })
```

and I got error message

Called stop() outside of a test context

what is wrong ?